# Is it fundamentally wrong to use volumeMounts.subPath in a production setup?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-efs

I am able to mount different directories to the same container at different mount points using `volumeMounts.subPath` attribute.

Is it OK to use this in production environment? I am using `AWS EFS` as my persistent storage.

[This](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath) doc says it is not recommended. What is the concern if this is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

It's absolutely fine to use the `subPath` in production

### Detailed answer

**Kubernetes example with `subPath` used.**

What this phrase "This sample subPath configuration is not recommended for production use." means is exactly this sample is not recommended, not the `subPath` usage.

The example contains frontend and backend applications' containers in a single pod which is fundamentally wrong approach for production usage (for testing it's applicable).

In production frontend and backend applications should be separated to different deployments, it will allow:

- manage front and back end applications separately
- fault tolerance - in single pod if one of the app crashes, the whole pod is affected
- pod are disposable units and for databases separate set of pods should be used (like statefulset), it allows to maintain sticky sessions and data persistence even if pod crashed

**`subPath` vulnerabilities**

First it's a good idea to figure out [how `subPath` works](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/04/fixing-subpath-volume-vulnerability/#kubernetes-background) to understand what risks/vulnerabilities can be introduced.

I found at least two ones:

- [CVE-2017-1002101](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60813)
- [CVE-2021-25741](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/104980)

Both are fixed as for today. It's very important to use last available versions which contain fixes for different issues (including both mentioned above).

Since kubernetes developers fix vulnerabilities related to `subPath` it can be safely used in production clusters.

Comment: Thanks @moonkotte for your very detailed answer. I am using kubectl version 1.23 and as I also saw that this vulnerability was fixed long back. I was concerned about "This sample subPath configuration is not recommended for production use." Which makes sense after your explanation. Kudos!!

Comment: FYI: I tried to edit your excellent answer, @moonkotte, to fix the first CVE link that has an extraneous `]` that has broken it, but SO won't let me edit by just removing one character, with this error: "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?" - not sure if you can still edit it and remove just the one character?  It's the link for CVE-2017-1002101.

Comment: @dossy Yes, indeed it was incorrect. Thank you for pointing this out, fixed.

Comment: @moonkotte I'm glad you could still edit it, thanks!  And as someone who is using multiple `subPath` volume mounts to the same Google Filestore volume in production, I was also confused and concerned by the statement in the official documentation - your interpretation of it makes a lot of sense, and the documentation really should be clarified to be less ambiguous.